# Trying out ksqldb with Azure Event Hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, ksqldb

I'm experimenting with ksqldb and Azure Event Hubs. When I try to start a new dockerised instance of ksqldb with Azure Event Hub as the Kafka Broker using this command:

`docker run -p 8088:8088 -e KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=<event-hub-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 -e KSQL_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8088/ -e KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID=default_ -e KSQL_KSQL_SINK_REPLICAS=3 -e KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3 -e KSQL_KSQL_INTERNAL_TOPIC_REPLICAS=3 -e KSQL_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL -e KSQL_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN -e KSQL_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"<connection string from shared access policy>\";" confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.28.2`

I get the following error:

`ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:96) io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException: Could not get Kafka cluster configuration! at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:96) at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.isKafkaAuthorizerEnabled(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:113) at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.isTopicAccessValidatorEnabled(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:96) at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.getAccessValidator(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:64) at io.confluent.ksql.security.KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.create(KsqlAuthorizationValidatorFactory.java:42) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:806) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:637) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:225) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.lambda$main$1(KsqlServerMain.java:82) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.tryStartApp(KsqlServerMain.java:115) at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:94) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition. at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165) at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.lambda$getConfig$0(KafkaClusterUtil.java:81) at io.confluent.ksql.util.ExecutorUtil.executeWithRetries(ExecutorUtil.java:100) at io.confluent.ksql.util.ExecutorUtil.executeWithRetries(ExecutorUtil.java:85) at io.confluent.ksql.util.ExecutorUtil.executeWithRetries(ExecutorUtil.java:70) at io.confluent.ksql.services.KafkaClusterUtil.getConfig(KafkaClusterUtil.java:80) ... 10 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.`

The networking policy of Event Hub is set to public and it isn't behind any firewall. What settings am I missing out to get this working?

Comment: UnknownTopicOrPartitionException - I think you need to pre-create a few topics like the ksql command topic. Otherwise, it could be an auth issue, rather than network, but it seems like it did connect, just couldn't get some topic it needs

Comment: Wihout SSL default port is 9092, I see you are using 9093. Don't know about azure, but is SSL enabled on your cluster? Probably check that and configure ksqlDB to work with SSL. But as @OneCricketeer suggested create the topic before hand and check